# Split html table rows to another column

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to for loop my data to render a table

```
my datas = [[1, 'count'], [2, 'count'], [3, 'count'], ..., ['total', 'count']]
```

continue to the days in this month

I would like render my data to the table like this
so when the for loop counter till 9, it will create/ move to another column and continue render data.

[image]

I have tried this but it goes horizontally:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <tr>
    {%for item in new_client_dict %}
    <td>{{ item.0 }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.1 }}</td>
    {%if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"9"%}
  </tr>
  <tr>
    {%endif%}
    {%endfor%}
  </tr>
</table>
```

[image]
Any suggestion? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using divisible_by to close `<tr>` and open a new row. Example:

```
<tr>
{%for item in items%}
<td>{{data}}</td>
{%if forloop.counter|divisible_by:"9"%}
</tr>
<tr>
{%endif%}
{%endfor%}
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't mind having those in separated tables (side by side in the same row), you are using it for days (max = 31, 4 columns with 9 rows), and you are using bootstrap (as in question tag) you could do something like that:

```
<div class='row'>


    {%for item in items%}
        {% if forloop.counter = "1" %} #I can't tell if this counter starts with 0 or one, be sure to make it the first interation number
            <div class='col-lg-3'>
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <tbody>
        {% endif %}
        {% if forloop.counter|divisible_by:"9" %}
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>
            <div class='col-lg-3'> # lg, sm, xl, choose your flavor
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
             #add header here #
            <tbody>
        {% endif %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.0 }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.1 }}</td>
        </tr>
     {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
            </table>
            </div>

</div>
```

Comment: @vinCi I'm pretty sure you could tweak the css (probably making your own separated file would be better) to achieve exactly what you wanted.
This code seems to work here on my settings (python 2.7, django 1.9)